# What the symbol $\subseteq$ represents generally?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

My book says that $\subset$ is used to represente any subset, proper or improper, needing in this case to show the anti symmetric property of sets. ($A = B \iff A \subset B \, \, \wedge \,\, B \subset A)$

And $\subseteq$ is used specifically to represent improper subsets. (In other words, $A \subseteq B \iff A = B) $

But i saw so many articles using $\subseteq$ and not $\subset$ then i am kinda suspicious about this definition.

If this definition is correct, why $\subseteq$ it's so used? Just because it helps to prove the equality betwen the sets?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your suspicion is justified. I advice you to use $\subset$ for subsets (proper as well as improper), and $\subsetneq$ for subsets that are proper when that is a relevant thing in the context.

Comment: What book are you reading?  I have _never_ seen $\subseteq$ used to denote equality between sets.

Comment: See the first answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50253/subset-vs-subseteq-when-not-referring-to-strict-inclusion?rq=1

Comment: I had a professor (a logician by practice) who was a bit picky about notation. He __never__ used $\subset$ and always used $\subseteq$ in its place. He also avoided $a/b$ when writing $\frac{a}{b}$, and threatened to give me a $0$ on a quiz because my fraction bar didn't fully cover the denominator. He was a cool guy though.

Comment: @ArthurFischer ok,so in what situation i may use $\subseteq$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is common practice to use $\subset$ to simply denote a subset, proper or not.  $\subseteq$ is used to mean the same thing.  This is mainly due to reasons of convenience.  I'm a pedant and prefer to use $\subset$ for proper subset, whereas $\subsetneq$ is convention for proper subsets.

I disagree that $\subseteq$ is used to represent improper subsets since we already have a good symbol for that: $=$

In reading though, you should interpret $\subset$ as subset, proper or not.  Context typically makes it clear though.

(Now imagine if primary and secondary educators decided to go on protest and use $<$ instead of $\leq$ for reasons of convenience).

Comment: ok, so in what situation i may use $\subseteq$?

Comment: I simply use it for subset.  Basically one has three choices of the (subset,proper subset) combination: $(\subseteq,\subset)$, $(\subseteq,\subsetneq)$, and $(\subset,\subsetneq)$ with the last one being most common, although I prefer the first.  The key thing is to just make sure your audience knows which one you're using.

Comment: The first convention is the most logical one, since it parallels the usual convention for ≤ and <.  Furthermore, it's becoming more popular.  Eventually it will only be old books that use ⊂ to mean "subset of, oh yeah and possibly equal though you'd never guess from the look of it".

Comment: The second convention is the most unambiguous one though, and avoids all possible confusion that might arise from the first and third coexisting.