# Examples of when inclusion is proper

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

I have several preimage and image statements to compare and I've completed the comparison part but I also need to give an example where the inclusion is proper.

1) $ $f  [$f^{-1}$[B]]$ $  $  \subseteq B$

2) $B  \subseteq $ $f^{-1}[f$[B]]

3) f  [$\bigcap$ $A_t$] $  \subseteq $     $\bigcap$[f [$A_t$]

4) f [$A_1$] \ f [$A_2$      $  \subseteq $      f [$A_1$ \ $A_2$]

[$A_t$] is an indexed family.

I do know that to be a proper class one class is strictly contained within a larger class and excludes some of its members. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about number 1?

In another of your questions, [Injective Equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655931/injective-equivalence), you have already shown that for conditions (2) and (3), equality holds just in the case where $f$ is injective.  So, for examples where the inclusion is strict, look for functions which are not injective.

(The simplest non-injective function is the function $f:\{0,1\}\to \{a\}$ given by $f(0)=f(1)=a$. This is useful to know when constructing counterexamples.)

Number 4 is similar.

---

As an aside, your terminology here is a bit off:

> I do know that to be a proper class one class is strictly contained within a larger class and excludes some of its members.

You mean a *proper subset* (or occasionally a *proper subclass*).  A *proper class* is something altogether different.

Another way to define a proper subset is to say that $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ if $A\subseteq B$ and $A\neq B$.  For this reason, some people use the notation $A\subsetneq B$ (to avoid the ambiguity over "$\subset$" - see here:  [$\subset$ vs $\subseteq$ when *not* referring to strict inclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50253/subset-vs-subseteq-when-not-referring-to-strict-inclusion?rq=1)).