# Is there any difference between $\subset$ and $\subseteq$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we write $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$ then we can assert that $A = B$ and the same goes for $A \subseteq B$ , $B \subseteq A$ ...

So then what is the essential difference between these two notations?

Comment: As they already mention below, some authors prefer $\subset$ for strict inclusion.  If you wish to be sure that you are understood, you can use \subsetneq for $\subsetneq$ to denote strict inclusion in an unambiguous manner.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [$\subset$ vs $\subseteq$ when \*not\* referring to strict inclusion](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/50253/74908)

Comment: @epimorphic is there a particular way to search for terms containing  ⊂ or other latex notation? If I google " ⊂ math stackexchange", it will just suggest the frontpage of this website, but no related results

Comment: I find it's best to use the latex code for the symbol while searching. I came across that post by entering `\subset \subseteq` in the site's search box in the bar at the top of the page. On Google you can use `\subset \subseteq site:math.stackexchange.com`. If you ever need to find the code for a symbol [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/) is really convenient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some sources make no difference between $\subset$ and $\subseteq$.

However, in other sources, $A\subseteq B$ allows the possibility that $A=B$, while $A\subset B$ specifically excludes that possibility.

From what you have said, it appears that in your text/course/whatever, there is no difference between the notations.  You should check with the front of the book, or with your teacher/instructor.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your convention. Some use $\subset$ for strict inclusion, some do not.  It depends on the author. I'd prefer $\subset$ for strict inclusion and $\subseteq$ for non-strict.  It is consistent with the usage for $<$ and $\le$.

Comment: This is what I initially assumed, however in my lecture notes I saw the assertion that $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A \implies A = B$ and was caught off-guard, so wanted to double check.