# Possible implications of $ ( A \cap B ) \subset ( C \cap D ) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering; if 
$$ ( A \cap B ) \subset ( C \cap D ) $$

Can anything be said about the relationship between $( A \cap B )$ and:
$$( A \cap C )$$
$$( A \cap D )$$
$$( B \cap C )$$
$$( B \cap D )$$

Comment: Absolutely nothing. A simple Venn diagram will show it.

Comment: @Bernard I do not think one could call a 4-set venn diagram particularly "*simple*."  Most people don't even know how to [draw one correctly](http://www.mbatious.com/prepnote/how-deal-four-sets-set-theory).  Also, (*using the convention that $\subset$ simply means subset, not* **proper** *subset*), surely one can conclude that $(A\cap B)$ is a subset of each of those four.  (*I do not understand why @ Bungo was downvoted and pressured to delete his post below*)

Comment: There was a post about $C \cap D \subset C$ etc. What was the flaw in that reasoning?

Comment: @ Olumide there was none.  I think @Bungo should undelete his post as it was, for all intents and purposes, correct and properly answered the question in my opinion.

Comment: @JMOravitz: Why should  $A\cap B$ be a subset of $A\cap C$, for instance?

Comment: @JMoravitz That result was what I expected but I did not want to mark it correct before others weighed in on it. Re diagrams, I am not a trained mathematician but I thought diagrams were not supposed to integral to any proof or otherwise.

Comment: Oh, actually. I might have been responsible for this. I overlooked the crucial "if" in the first line. (I keep telling my ophthalmologists that I've trouble reading. But according to them my eye side is fine... Maybe I'm just tired.) So, sorry about that. Should @Bungo undelete his post, please let me know so that I can change my downvote into an upvote.

Comment: @Bernard let $x\in A\cap B$.  Then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$.  As a result, we know that $x\in A$.  Furthermore, since $x\in A\cap B$ and $A\cap B\subset C\cap D$ we know that $x\in C\cap D$.  This implies by definition that $x\in C$ and $x\in D$.  In particular we know that $x\in C$.  Thus we have learned that $x\in A$ and $x\in C$.  Then by definition $x\in A\cap C$.  Thus by definition of subset relation, this implies that $A\cap B\subset A\cap C$.

Comment: OK. Intuitively, I would have bet we could produce a counter-example!

Comment: @Stefan I've updated my answer with an explicit rephrasing of how I interpreted the question. I apologize if this is not what the OP was asking, but after rereading the question several times, I am having difficulty interpreting it any other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

**Edit:** I received some downvotes and "this doesn't answer the question" comments which I don't really understand unless I grossly misinterpreted the question.

Here is my interpretation. @OP, please let me know if this is not what you intended.

> If we assume that $(A \cap B) \subset (C \cap D)$, then can anything be said about the relation between $(A \cap B)$ and any of $(A \cap C)$, $(A \cap D)$, $(B \cap C)$, and $(B \cap D)$?

Assuming this rephrasing of the question is valid, here is my answer.

---

We have:
$$A \cap B \subset A$$
$$A \cap B \subset B$$
and
$$A \cap B \subset C \cap D \subset C$$
$$A \cap B \subset C \cap D \subset D$$
Therefore, $A\cap B$ is contained in each of the sets $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, so it is contained in any intersection of these sets.

---

**P.S.** In response to the comment by **G Cab**, I interpret $\subset$ to mean "is a (not necessarily proper) subset of".

Comment: Actually, a distinction should be made between  $ \subset $ and $\subseteq$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I have added an explicit rephrasing of (how I interpret) the question. If you interpret it some other way, I would appreciate it if you would add a comment explaining how you read it, because after rereading it a few times, I don't see a viable alternative.

Comment: @Bungo Here, have my upvote (;

Comment: @Stefan Thanks! :-)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm awarding @Bungo the answer not because his is the most rigorous (they all are) but because he was the first.

Answer (score 3):

It depends exactly what is meant by "$\subset$." I've seen that symbol used to denote both proper subset, and possibly improper subset.

**First interpretation ($\subsetneq$)**: Suppose $A=B$ and $C=D$, and $A\subsetneq C$. Then the hypothesis holds, but we do **not** have $A\cap B\subsetneq A\cap C$ (and similarly for the other three pieces of the question).

**Second interpretation ($\subseteq$)**: Since $A\cap B\subseteq C\cap D$, we have $A\cap B\subseteq C$. Thus $A\cap (A\cap B)\subseteq A\cap C$, that is, $A\cap B\subseteq A\cap C$. The other three pieces of the question are similar.

---

That is: from the (a priori stronger) hypothesis $A\cap B\subsetneq C\cap D$, all we can conclude is that $A\cap B\subseteq A\cap C$ (and etc.). The latter inclusion may be improper.

Answer (score 3):

*Unfortunately, the original answer by @Bungo was correct but for some reason he was pressured to delete it.  If he decides to answer again, I encourage people to upvote that answer and for the question asker to select it as the accepted answer.*

---

As a foreword, one of the comments on @Bungo's post was about the distinction between the use of the symbols $\subset$ and $\subseteq$.  In some contexts $X\subset Y$ implies that $X\subseteq Y$ and $X\neq Y$, i.e. that $X$ is a **proper** subset of $Y$.  However, [in many other contexts we do not make a distinction between the two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50253/subset-vs-subseteq-when-not-referring-to-strict-inclusion).  That is to say, depending on the author, $X\subset Y$ does **not** imply $X\neq Y$.  Notably, [Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Rudin) follows the convention that $\subset$ does not imply being a proper subset.

---

> **Definition 1:** A set $X$ is said to be a **subset** of the set $Y$, written with symbols as $X\subseteq Y$ or as $Y\supseteq X$, if and only if every element which happens to be an element of $X$ also happens to be an element of $Y$.

To prove that a set $X$ is a subset of a set $Y$, one can take a generic element of $X$, often denoted as $x$, and show that certain properties of the sets in question imply that it is also an element of $Y$.  If we did not specify anything about the element $x$ apart from it being an element of $X$, this would imply that it is true for *all* elements in $X$, which implies the result.

> **Definition 2:** The **intersection** of two sets $X$ and $Y$, written as $X\cap Y$, is the set of all elements which are in both $X$ and $Y$ simultaneously.  That is to say, $x\in X\cap Y$ if and only if $x\in X$ **and** $x\in Y$.

---

Given that $A\cap B\subseteq C\cap D$, let $x\in A\cap B$.

Then by definition 2, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$.

Furthermore, since $x\in A\cap B$ and $A\cap B\subseteq C\cap D$ by definition 1 this implies that $x\in C\cap D$.  Then by definition 2, this further implies that $x\in C$ and $x\in D$.

Thus, for any $x\in A\cap B$ it follows that all of the following are true: $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ and $x\in C$ and $x\in D$.  Thus, $x\in A\cap B\cap C\cap D$ and therefore by definition 1 $A\cap B\subseteq A\cap B\cap C\cap D$.

In particular then, by looking at only two of the four statements at a time, this implies that $x\in A\cap B, x\in A\cap C, x\in A\cap D, x\in B\cap C, x\in B\cap D$ and $x\in C\cap D$.

Then by definition 1, one has $A\cap B$ is a subset of all of the sets listed in question.

Comment: Thank you, I deleted my answer because I was on a mobile phone in a restaurant when the downvotes and "this doesn't answer the question" comments started arriving. I thought I must have grossly misinterpreted the question. I didn't relish attempting to edit/clarify my answer from the phone app :-) I'll go ahead and edit/undelete now.