# prove that if A is a subset of B, B is a subset of C, and C is a subset of A, then A=B and B=C

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To prove A=B, I must prove that A is a subset of B and B is a subset of A. A is a subset of B is already given. So all that is left is to prove B is a subset of A.

Is it suffice to say that since A is a subset of B, B is a subset of C, and C is a subset of A, by transitive property B is a subset of A.

Comment: Yes. It is. Adding more characters so I can post comment.

Comment: Do you mean I should add more characters on my post so you can post comments?

Comment: No I mean that I had to add characters to post my comment. :) Try posting a comment with one word it won't work.

Comment: Probably you need to prove the transitive property. Or have you already seen a proof of it?

Comment: No I have not. That's why i asked because I feel that simply stating its transitive property is not really a proof

Comment: @user137243: Can you tell me where this problem is taken from? *(I don't care if it's hw.)*

Comment: @NotNotLogical: You can achieve the character minimum with invisible characters by adding something like this to a comment: `${}{}{}{}{}$` For example, see [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922797/what-is-the-meaning-of-set-theoretic-notation-0-and-1/922815#comment1905256_922814). Also, I'm not sure who downvoted this question. It seems perfectly clear and reasonable to me. I have upvoted.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15188/how-to-prove-a-subset-b-b-subset-c-c-subset-a-rightarrow-b-c? That question was shown in the sidebar among the related questions.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the problem deals wit two *separate* issues!

Check transitivity:
$$A\subseteq B\subseteq C\implies A\subseteq C$$

Check antisymmetry:
$$A\subseteq C\subseteq A\implies A=C$$

*(These are rather different!)*

Answer (score 1):

If you are given that $A\subseteq B\subseteq C\subseteq A$, then yes you can. To be more specific, given any $x\in B$, $x$ is also in $C$, and also in $A$, so $B\subseteq A$. Use a simlar argument to show that $B=C$.