# If $A$ is a subset of $B$, $B$ is a subset of $C$ and $C$ is a subset of $A$, prove that $A=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ is a subset of $B$, $B$ is a subset of $C$ and $C$ is a subset of $A$, prove that $A=C$

Please help I didn't get any idea to solve.

Comment: Well, how do you define "subset"? How do you prove that two sets are equal?

Comment: You have to "cook together" two definitions: that of (set) *inclusion* : $\subseteq$ and that of (set) *equality* : $=$. Both are expressed in terms of the "basic" set *relation* : $\in$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prove that if A is a subset of B, B is a subset of C, and C is a subset of A, then A=B and B=C](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757214/prove-that-if-a-is-a-subset-of-b-b-is-a-subset-of-c-and-c-is-a-subset-of-a-th)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- $\subseteq$ is a transitive relation on sets.
- $\subseteq$ is an antisymmetric relation on sets.

Comment: what is the hint here?

Comment: Apply both hints. E.g. what can you conclude from $A\subseteq B\wedge B\subseteq C$ if $\subseteq$ is transitive? And what can you conclude from $A\subseteq C\wedge C\subseteq A$ if $\subseteq$ is antisymmetric?

Comment: I did not understand. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: What is your answer to both questions in my former comment?